# Java regex between strings multiple times on same line

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to extract the values between `[::[' and ']::]'. The problem I am having is there are multiple instances of this in the same string and it is only picking up the first one. Any help with my regex? here is my code:

Sample input: `line = "TEST [::[NAME]::] HERE IS SOMETHING [::[DATE]::] WITH SOME MORE [::[Last]::]";`

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[::\\[(.*?)\\]::\\]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your regex is OK. What you need to do is cycle through the matches, a `Matcher` can match several times!

```
while (m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

A `Matcher` will try again from the end of the last match (unless you use `\G` but that's pretty special)

Comment: Worked perfect. Awesome. Thank You!